# Tikz Matrix: get boxes with the same size and text vertically centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want to draw a certain process/flow/block diagram. So I used [this TiKZ Galery example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/BER-measurement/) as starter:

[image]

Using this approach I came up with the MWE below:

[image]

Now this does not look nice for a flow diagram. I want all boxes the same size (of that matrix row).

I can fix this by adding a invisible line to process B:

```
{Process B\\\phantom{spacer}}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How this is also not desirable, because now this text is not vertically centered anymore.

How can I:

- Get all matrix boxes (for that row) the same size.
- Still keep text vertically (and horizontally) centered.

Thanks

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
    column sep=5mm,
    row sep=1cm,
    nodes={draw,
      line width=1pt,
      anchor=center, 
      text centered,
      align=center,text width=3cm, 
      rounded corners,
      minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=8mm
    },
    nodes in empty cells, 
    ]
  {
    {Process A long description}
    &
    {Process B}\\
  };  
  \draw[line width=1pt] (m-1-1)--(m-1-2)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply increase the `minimum height` for all nodes.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
    column sep=5mm,
    row sep=1cm,
    nodes={draw,
      line width=1pt,
      anchor=center, 
      text centered,
      align=center,text width=3cm, 
      rounded corners,
      minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm
    },
    nodes in empty cells, 
    ]
  {
    {Process A long description}
    &
    {Process B}\\
  };  
  \draw[line width=1pt] (m-1-1)--(m-1-2)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```